# How to compute the statistical power of this normality test in R language

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, statistical-inference, order-statistics

I've written the following code  in `R` program:

```
n=10
delta <- vector()
for (i in 1:10000){
x <- rt(n, 1)
x <- sort(x)
z <- pnorm(x, mean(x), sd(x))
delta[i] <- sum(abs(z-seq(1,n)/n))/sum(pmax(z, seq(1,n)/n))
}
```

I want to compute the statistical power of  the proposed normality test via simulation studies with 10000 iterations, assuming different sample sizes and various alternative distributions. For a fixed sample size n and for a pre-assumed alternative distribution, (like t-student with degree of freedom 1), the power of the test is computed as the percentage of samples out of 10000 Monte-Carlo simulated samples from the pre-assumed distribution which were rejected to follow normal distribution based on the used test. I was wondering if someone could tell me how I can compute the statistical power of this normality test in `R`?

Comment: maybe better suited for https://stats.stackexchange.com/ or https://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Vetting R code is off topic here--and also on the stat site. But it is reasonable to explore power and sample size computations for specific tests. Please describe in math notation the relevant normality test you are using.

Comment: Vetting R code is off topic here--and [also on the stat site}(https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/540480/how-to-compute-the-statistical-power-of-this-normality-test-in-r-language#comment994637_540480) But it is reasonable to explore power and sample size computations for specific tests. Please describe in math notation the relevant normality test you are using. – BruceET 26 mins ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose a test of normality is performed at the 5% level. This means that it will reject (have P-value below 5%) with probability $0.05$ for a random sample from a normal population. (A test at *significance level* 5%.)

One hopes that
the test rejects with larger probability
for a random sample from a non-normal distribution (its *power*).

No normality test has good power for *all* non-normal distributions, but the Shapio-Wilk test
works reasonably well for a wide variety of
non-normal distributions. This test is implemented in R as `shapiro.test`.

Below I show how to use R to find the power
of the S-W test for samples of size $n=10$ from
Student's t distribution with $\nu = 1$ degrees of freedom (a standard Cauchy distribution).

For one such sample, the S-W test in R looks like this. Notice that S-W does not reject for this
particular sample.

```
set.seed(826)
shapiro.test(rt(10, 1))

        Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  rt(10, 1)
W = 0.96613, p-value = 0.8529
```

one can use `$`-notation to get just the P-value:

```
set.seed(826);  shapiro.test(rt(10,1))$p.val
[1] 0.8528541
```

In your question, you propose using $10^4$ iterations, but I think using $10^5$ iterations
is more likely to give useful results.

Here is a simulation in R to approximate the power of the S-W normality test against the alternative that the sample is from $\mathsf{T}(\nu = 1).$ The power is about $0.5912\pm 0.0031.$

```
set.seed(2021)
pv = replicate(10^5, shapiro.test(rt(10,1))$p.val)
mean(pv <= 0.05)  # power
[1] 0.59117
2*sd(pv <= 0.05)/sqrt(10^5)
[1] 0.003109279
```

A run with samples of size $n = 20$ (not shown)
gave about 87% power. Thus the S-W normality test
is not so good at rejecting Cauchy samples of size 10, and considerably better at rejecting such samples of size 20.

Notes: (1) The numeric vector `pv` contains $100\,000$ P-values. The logical vector `pv <= 0.05` contains $100\,000$ `TRUE`s and `FALSE`s (True upon rejection). Its `mean` is its proportion of
`TRUE`s.

The last line of code shows an approximate 95% margin of simulation error; we
are getting almost 2-place accuracy from $10^5$ iterations. (The asymptotic Wald CI is used; it works well for $100,000$ iterations.)

(2) While this style of simulation using `$`-notation
ensures that I am using exactly the version of the
Shapiro-Wilk test that is implemented in R, and
the code is easy to write. However, this is not
the fastest possible code because R formats the
entire test output at each iteration, while we
use only the P-value.

(3) If you can write a function that returns the P-value of *your* test of normality, then you can
use analogous R code (with `replicate`) to explore its power.